# ksh: evaluate a line read from file

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I have got a properties file - prop that has the below line:

```
table1_prop=$USER.table1;dir1;dir2
```

In my script I read the file but I am unable to evaluate $USER.

```
while read record_line; do
   if [ ! -z "$record_line" -a "$record_line" != " " ]; then
          record_array=(`echo eval "$record_line" | cut -d '=' -f 2| sed 's/;/\n/g'`)  
   fi
done
```

Evaluate doesn't work. I tried backquote `. Any help.

Comment: Note: `The XSI extensions specifying the -a and -o binary primaries and the '(' and ')' operators have been marked obsolescent`  (from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)  That is, instead of `[ ! -z "$record_line" -a "$record_line" != " " ]`, you should write `[ -n "$record_line" ] && [ "$record_line" != " " ]`.

Comment: Try something like: `while IFS='=.;' read a b c d e; do b=${b#$}; echo a=$a, b=${!b}, c=$c, d=$d; done < input`

Comment: wouldn't it  be `eval echo ....`? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been a while...but if you still have the problem...that code works with the property file you've provided.

```
    #!/bin/ksh

    while read record_line
    do
       if [[ ! -z $record_line && $record_line != " " ]]; then
            set -A record_array $(sed 's|;| |g' <<<"${record_line#*=*}")
       fi
    done < ./prop.txt

    for ((i=0;i<${#record_array[*]};i++)); do
            print $i" "${record_array[$i]}
    done
```

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed this